# Can't build a static-library C++/SFML project for Windows XP in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, static-libraries, sfml

**I want to create a C++/SFML game that runs in Windows XP and doesn't ask the user for MSVCP140.dll.**

I'm using SFML 2.4.1 for Windows (Visual C++ 14 (2015) - 32-bit) with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015.

I'm working in Windows 10 and using Windows XP in a virtual machine to test this.

I tried to ship whatever it needs with the program, but at some point it asks for something that isn't a file.

So I believe I have to make it a static-library project.

And so I followed [the tutorial for SFML 2.4 and Visual Studio](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/start-vc.php).

Reproducing my steps adapted to the case:

- I open Visual Studio > New Project > C++ (.NET Framework 4.5.2) > Win32 Console Application > name it "test" > check "Empty project" > click Finish
- Create a "main.cpp" inside "Source Files" branch
- Put "SFML-2.4.1" folder into "C:\"
- Open the Property window for my project
- Set Configuration to "All Configurations"
- General > Platform Toolset > Visual Studio 2015 - Windows XP (v140_xp)
- C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directiories > "C:\SFML-2.4.1\include"
- Linker > General > Additional Library Directiories > "C:\SFML-2.4.1\lib"
- Set Configuration to "Debug"
- C/C++ > Preprocessor > Preprocessor Definitions > prepend "SFML_STATIC;"
- C/C++ > Code Generation > Runtime Library > Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)
- Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies > prepend "sfml-graphics-s-d.lib;sfml-window-s-d.lib;sfml-system-s-d.lib;"
- Set Configuration to "Release"
- C/C++ > Preprocessor > Preprocessor Definitions > prepend "SFML_STATIC;"
- C/C++ > Code Generation > Runtime Library > Multi-threaded (/MT)
- Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies > prepend "sfml-graphics-s.lib;sfml-window-s.lib;sfml-system-s.lib;"

Then I go back to the project, copy the code from the tutorial to "main.cpp" and try to run Build Solution.

> Debug (x86): **171 Errors and 87 Warnings**
>   
> First error: *LNK2038 mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MTd_StaticDebug' in main.obj*
>   
> Release (x86): **105 Errors and 1 Warning**
>   
> First error: *LNK2038 mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in main.obj*

I thought I did everything needed for a static-library project, but something is still dynamic. I don't know what to do from here. Please, help?